# How to make c++ decorator patterns easier to use for memory management?

Tags: c++, decorator

Are there any existing tricks for making decorator patterns in C++ easier to use with respect to memory management?

If I use a std::auto_ptr inside my decorator, I can create an object in the nested-new style and the pointers will be deleted properly. However, if I use the style of passing pointers to stack-allocated objects, then we incorrectly delete those objects. Is there a way to make this work properly or enforce only one style?

```
#if 0
    T0 t0;
    T1 t1(&t0);
    T2 t2(&t1);
    T3 t3(&t2);
#else
    T3 t3(new T2(new T1(new T0)));
#endif
```

I've defined the following simple Test classes.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <memory>

class TI {
public:
    virtual void test() = 0;
    virtual ~TI() {}
};

class TD : public TI {
public:
  TD(TI *ti) : _ti(ti) {}
  virtual void test() { return _ti->test(); }
private:
  std::auto_ptr<TI> _ti;
};

class T0 : public TI {
public:
    T0() { qDebug("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
    virtual void test() { qDebug("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
    virtual ~T0() { qDebug("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
};

class T1 : public TD {
public:
    T1(TI *ti) : TD(ti) { qDebug("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
    virtual void test() {  TD::test(); qDebug("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
    virtual ~T1() { qDebug("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
};

class T2 : public TD {
public:
    T2(TI *ti) : TD(ti) { qDebug("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
    virtual void test() {  TD::test(); qDebug("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
    virtual ~T2() { qDebug("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
};

class T3 : public TD {
public:
    T3(TI *ti) : TD(ti) { qDebug("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
    virtual void test() {  TD::test(); qDebug("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
    virtual ~T3() { qDebug("%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
};
```

Comment: C++ makes decorator pattern a pain to use, I got rid of all of them in my code, I don't recommend it unless for existing code.

Comment: Don't use `std::auto_ptr` it's deprecated because it's not safe to handle in the same way that a `std::shared_ptr` is

Comment: @yngum: It's useful for this: `ReadableKey(EncryptedKey(LicenseKey))`

Comment: @Mgetz: I don't have a C++11 capable compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to our company rules, your first variant is required `T0 t0; T1 t1(&t0);`, since the creator (caller) is responsible to destroy elements, it has created. In such a case does not matter, wheater instances t0 and t1 are created on heap or on stack.

The second version `T3 t3(new T2(new T1(new T0)));` sounds reasonable, as long as one can rely on some kind of garbage collection (like c# does, or shared_ptr emulates). At the end, id depends on the coding style and frameworks available.

Comment: The nice thing about the nested news is the ability to have factory methods for commonly used sets: `TD *t3210() { return new T3(new T2(new T1(new T0)))); }`. The stack method makes using the code a bit of pain to others since it requires so many lines, it interferes with the readability of their own code.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But the implementation is probably difficult. What about adding pointer to itself as a member of the class and overwriting the new operator to store it. Later delete operator could check this member, and either release memory or do nothing. Is it too crazzy?

Comment: @dousin: Quite crazy, IMHO. That member will need to be initialized in the constructor, but that will overwrite the assignment from `operator new()`. If you are willing to add a check in the destructor, just add a `bool` member variable and set it with `t3.setDeleteOnDestroy()` or something.

Comment: I decided to go with the stack approach. That is, the caller is responsible for management of memory passed in as parameters. The worst case here is a memory leak where as the other approach will segfault. Also, to alleviate code readability issues, I've decided to create helper classes for common sets of decorators that create all of the child objects as members.

Comment: Actually, that's not entirely true. I _did_ find a solution, but it was ugly. If you make constructor explicit and takes an auto_ptr, then I think it works, but it makes for really long, ugly, hard-to-read code.